# Bootstrap Column Overflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a 4x3 grid of results similar to [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/). The results are paginated and a page can contain zero to twelve results.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var result in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>@result.Name</h3>
                <p>@result.CreatedBy</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This actually seems to work perfectly; if there are more than 4 results they wrap to a new row, however it seems like a bit of a hack and I am concerned that there may be some undesirable side effects.

Is this approach OK? If not, what is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that it wasn't working as perfectly as I initially thought; as soon as the content in each column differed in height the layout broke.

What I ended up doing was lifting a nice little extension method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709793/193460) and updating my markup to this:

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Partition(4))
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var program in row)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <h2>@program.Name</h2>
                    <p>@program.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```