# Applying "where" clause (LINQ) on even rows only [C#]

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string having two different types of data in alternating rows (*i.e. two rows make one record*). I want to select only those records where length of 2nd (*i.e. even row*) is less than 1000.

I have tried this but it results in selecting only the even*th* row and discards the odd row:

```
var lessthan1000Length = recordsFile.Where((src, index) => src.Length<1000 && index%2 != 0);
```

**Sample data from recordsFile**

```
2012-12-04 | 10:45 AM | Lahore
Added H2SO4 in the solution. Kept it in the lab temperature for 10 minutes    
2012-12-04 | 10:55 AM | Lahore
Observed the pH of the solution.     
2012-12-04 | 11:20 AM | Lahore
Neutralized the solution to maintain the pH in 6-8 range
```

Thanks for your guidance.

***P.S: Kindly note that the results are required in the form of `List<string>` as we have to make a new dataset from it.***

Comment: So use `index%2 != 0` instead? It starts with the 0th one, not the 1st one (zero-based index).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Use `!=` or `==', it doesn't matter as it starts selecting only even, odd rows respectively. I want both rows of the record. Please note that both odd and even row combine to form one record. For example row 353 and row 354 together make one record. I can't select any single row out of them

Comment: The sample data appears to use three rows per record (with each third record a blank line). Is that correct or have you just posted it that way?

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry! Its not 3 rows. I just posted this way.

Comment: Ah, I did not understand immediately that you wanted to "pair up" the entries such that the first two go together, and so on. It reminds me of threads like [Split an `IEnumerable<T>` into fixed-sized chunks (return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` where the inner sequences are of fixed length) _duplicate_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709626/). However it could be simpler when we simply want "chunks" of ength 2 (pairs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> result = recordFile
  .Select( (str, index) => new {str, index})
  .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2, x => x.str)
  .Where(g => g.Last().Length < 1000)
  .Select(g => g.First() + g.Last())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var odds = recordsFile.Where((str, index) => index % 2 == 0);
var evens = recordsFile.Where((str, index) => index % 2 == 1);

var records = odds.Zip(evens, (odd, even) => new { odd, even })
    .Where(pair => pair.even.Length < 1000);

foreach (var record in records)
    Console.WriteLine(record);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander so much. There is an issue that I want to select these records and put it into another dataset, so I need them to be in the form of strings (`List<string>` will be best), but its not allowing me to cast the `records' into List<string>. Can you please guide there?

Comment: Should it not be the other way round? Even numbers are 0,2,4, ... I think the modulo must be 0 for evens and not for odds

Answer (score 1):

If you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework team's "Interactive Extensions" you get a nice extension method that can help you.

```
var query = 
    from pair in lines.Buffer(2)
    where pair[1].Length < 1000
    select pair;

var results = query.ToList();
```

From your sample data I get this:

[image: results]

Just NuGet "Ix-Main" to get the extension methods - there are a lot more there than just `.Buffer` and many of them are super useful.

Comment: Thanks. That is something new for me. Insha'Allah I will surely look into it. But remember that we need pairs back. Not just even line. Please update it accordingly

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - I've updated the answer to pull back the pairs. It is even simpler now.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer seems to work fine.

Alternatively, you can create a method to turn a sequence (with an even number of terms) into a sequence of pairs. I guess something like:

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> PairUp<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src)
{
  using (var e = src.GetEnumerator)
  {
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
      var first = e.Current;

      if (!e.MoveNext())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Count of source must be even"); // OR: yield break; OR yield return Tuple.Create(first, default(T)); yield break;
      var second = e.Current;

      yield return Tuple.Create(first, second);
    }
  }
}
```

With that you could do `recordsFile.PairUp().Where(t => t.Item2.Length < 1000)` or similar.

Edit: Since you want the two "parts" concatenated as strings, that would be `recordsFile.PairUp().Where(t => t.Item2.Length < 1000).Select(t => t.Item1 + t.Item2)`.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe. Alexandar's answer was almost perfect. Just issue was in having strings back