# c# split list by chunk of items

Tags: c#

I got a list of data like bellow. Here I already added 50 demo items in list. Now I want to make a chunk of list splitted by 10 items in each chunk. How can I do it? I already tried like bellow using `while` loop and `GroupBy` but I am not getting idea what's the best way to do it? All I need is from this 50 items it should be make a new list which will `GroupBy` 10 items.

Model:

```
class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public static List<Data> data { get; set; } = new List<Data>();
    }
```

Main Program:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)//seeding 50 example data to global class
        {
            Data.data.Add(new Data
            {
                Id = i,
                Text = null,
            });
        }
    

        var chunkList = new List<Data>();//i need a chunk of list devided by 10 items in each chunk
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in Data.data)
        {
            do
            {
                chunkList.AddRange(chunkList.GroupBy(u => u.Id).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList());//this logic is wrong
                count++;
            } while (count == 10);
            
        }


        Console.WriteLine("");
        
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709626/split-an-ienumerablet-into-fixed-sized-chunks-return-an-ienumerableienumerab/13710023#13710023 Also check the link as duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Here I found most easiest solution for my problem. I am using [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)
and using `Batch` as you can see bellow.

```
int size = 10;
var chunkList = Data.data.Batch(size);
```

Comment: Even if a third party lib can do this for you, it doesn't really answer the question, nor does a link only answer which this basically amounts to. The algorithm is actually quite simple and I encourage you to still try and implement it yourself or by looking at the suggested duplicate. Solving yourself and/or understanding what the solution is goes a long way to helping not only the problem at hand but also giving you the tools to solve other problems that will undoubtedly present themselves to you in the future

Comment: You are right @pinkfloydx33