# Inside of using block, need to dispose and reinstantiate

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to enhance the performance of writing thousands of rows to a db using EF. I have found that the speed of SaveChanges() degrades over time within a single context, and disposing and recreating the context after n inserts can help this.

```
using(Context context = new Context())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        context.Collection.AddObject(line);
        if (i % 100 == 0)
        {
            context.SaveChanges()
            // Here I would like to call dispose on context and then create a new one
        }
     }
}
```

Of course, I need to use using or do something similar because there is a lot more going on and I need to ensure that dispose will be called if an exception gets thrown at any time.

Any ideas? I know I can declare the context outside of a try block, and then have a finally with context.Dispose(). I obviously don't want to do that though.

EDIT: I realized the code snippet I posted doesn't totally show why I am trying to do this. The for loop calls context.SaveChanges() in other spots outside of the IF statement. So when the IF evaluates to true, I've called SaveChanges() a number of times already.

Comment: Where is the data actually coming from? Does it depend on `i`? That significantly affects the simplest way of achieving this.

Comment: I have a list of string arrays, (think CSV file) and I use i to maintain the index.

Comment: Okay, so it's basically just a collection? Right, MoreLINQ to the rescue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you basically want to process a collection in batches. That's simple using [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) ([also on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq)):

```
foreach (var batch in dataToUpload.Batch(100))
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        foreach (var item in batch)
        {
            ...
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Aside from anything else, that *describes* what you're trying to achieve (IMO) much more clearly than using one loop with a check for `i % 100` in it.

(Original link to http://morelinq.googlecode.com is no longer valid, replaced with current GitHub link)

Answer (score 3):

Because identifiers inside of a `using` are read only, you can't just set it to a new object.  I'd say the best option is to do exactly what you said you don't want to do and use a `try/finally` instead of a using:

```
Context context = null;
try
{
    context = new Context();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        context.Collection.AddObject(line);
        if (i % 100 == 0)
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            context = new Context();
        }
    }
}
finally { context.Dispose(); }
```

While you could technically do what you want by creating a new disposable object that wraps another disposable object and allows that wrapped object to be mutated, it would be a poor practice.  C# *specifically* goes out of its way to make the given identifier read-only because it is particularly confusing for that object to be changing during the `using` block, and it makes the code much harder to reason about, but if you really want to do it, you can:

```
using (var context = new EvilMutableDisposableWrapper<Context>(new Context()))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        context.Wrapped.Collection.AddObject(line);
        if (i % 100 == 0)
        {
            context.Wrapped.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            context.Wrapped = new Context();
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't do this though.

Comment: I think the OP contracted themselves. They first said `I have found that the speed of SaveChanges() degrades over time within a single context` and then said `I know I can declare the context outside of a try block, and then have a finally with context.Dispose().` It stands to reason that this won't yield acceptable results for the OP.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I fail to see a contradiction between those two statements.

Comment: Nevermind, I read the code you posted wrong. However, the OP was literally saying they can't have a *single context open* over an extended period and then said they *could create one and dispose at the end.*

Comment: Just to clarify: IF you call SaveChanges() x number of times within the same context, the speed of SaveChanges() degrades. If you create a new context every n times, where n < x, you can see (or at least I do) a performance improvement.

Comment: @mattm, if you look at Servy's code, he is building a new context on every break.

Comment: +1 (not sure if it going to help performance, but answers the question). I'd personally do it other way around: chunk data and use normal `using` pattern for saving (as now present by @JonSkeet answer).

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
const int ChunkSize = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i += ChunkSize)
{
    using(Context context = new Context())
    {
        for(int j = i; j < i + ChunkSize && j < numberOfLines; j++)
        {
            // if needed, use j within this loop, not i
            context.Collection.AddObject(line);
        }
        context.SaveChanges()
     }
}
```