# Calculating frame index based on new frame rate for video generation

Tags: c#, .net, video, frame-rate

My .NET application as a sequential list of images representing each frame of a video recorded at 30 frames per second.

```
00000001.png
00000002.png
00000003.png
...
99999999.png
```

Now I want to reorder this list so it can generate a video based on the following parameters:

```
Start Frame Index: 100
Direction:         Forward
Output Speed:      100 FPS
Duration:          10 seconds
```

So far I have something like this:

```
var originalFrameRate = 30D;
var originalFrameTime = 1D / originalFrameRate;
var originalStartFrameIndex = 100; // 00000100.png.
// Assume [originalFrames] will be filled with image file names from above.
var originalFrames = new List<string>
(new string [] { "0000003.png", "0000002.png", ..., "99999999.png", });

var targetFrameRate 100; // FPS.
var targetDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
var targetFrameCount = speed * targetDuration.Seconds;
var targetFrames = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < targetFrameCount; i++)
{
    // How to map the original list from 30 FPS to 100 FPS?
    targetFrames.Add(originalFrames [originalStartFrameIndex + ???]);
}
```

In the above example, the output would be targetFrames being filled with the appropriate file name based on the variables names `targetXXX`.

Any suggestions on how to map this would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the output video will always be generated at the original frame rate. The length of the target video will of course change. If the original FPS is lower than the target, we will repeat frames. Otherwise we will be skipping them.

Comment: Just so I understand - are you trying to *skip* frames so that it matches the duration you want? Or... on rereading, maybe it's the opposite: duplicating frames?

Comment: `Output speed` defines how you *skip* or duplicate frames. `Duration` is the *end condition*. Start from `Start Frame Index`, stop when total number of frames in `targetFrames` is more than `Duration / Output Speed`. FPS is tricky, in your case for `100 fps` out of `30 fps` you will have to output every frame `3.333333(3)` times (means sometimes 4 frames). To check when it is `4` - again, calculate current time and add `30 fps` to see if it's goes over `1 second` or not.

Comment: Yes. If the original FPS is lower than the target, we will repeat frames. Otherwise we will be skipping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to expand upon Vincent's answer to fix a problem I noticed: when scaling from 30fps to 100fps, frame 0 is repeated a fourth time (a frame pattern of `0000 111 222 3333`) when I was expecting `000 111 2222`. Not a big deal since it's probably just a matter of preference (whether you want the fractional "adjustment" to happen on an even or odd frame), but then I went down the rabbit hole and built an iterator class that can handle just about any scenario, including fractional framerates.

(Using a generic iterator has the added bonus of not requiring the frames to be `string` - if you wanted to represent each frame as a class, you could do that, too.)

```
public sealed class FramerateScaler<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _source;
    private readonly double _inputRate;
    private readonly double _outputRate;
    private readonly int _startIndex;

    public double InputRate { get { return _inputRate; } }
    public double OutputRate { get { return _outputRate; } }
    public int StartIndex { get { return _startIndex; } }

    public TimeSpan InputDuration {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((1 / _inputRate) * (_source.Count() - StartIndex)); }
    }

    public TimeSpan OutputDuration {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((1 / _outputRate) * this.Count()); }
    }

    public FramerateScaler(
        double inputRate, double outputRate, 
        IEnumerable<T> source, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        _source = source;
        _inputRate = inputRate;
        _outputRate = outputRate;
        _startIndex = startIndex;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ScalingFrameEnumerator<T>(_inputRate, _outputRate, _source, _startIndex);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }

    private sealed class ScalingFrameEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        internal readonly double _inputRate;
        internal readonly double _outputRate;
        internal readonly int _startIndex;

        private readonly List<T> _source;

        private readonly double _rateScaleFactor;
        private readonly int _totalOutputFrames;
        private int _currentOutputFrame = 0;

        public ScalingFrameEnumerator(
            double inputRate, double outputRate, 
            IEnumerable<T> source, int startIndex)
        {
            _inputRate = inputRate;
            _outputRate = outputRate;
            _source = source.ToList();
            _startIndex = startIndex;

            _rateScaleFactor = _outputRate / _inputRate;
            // Calculate total output frames from input duration
            _totalOutputFrames = (int)Math.Round(
                (_source.Count - startIndex) * _rateScaleFactor, 0);
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                return _source[_startIndex + 
                    (int)Math.Ceiling(_currentOutputFrame / _rateScaleFactor) - 1];
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Nothing unmanaged to dispose
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _currentOutputFrame++;
            return ((_currentOutputFrame - 1) < _totalOutputFrames);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _currentOutputFrame = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And a set of tests covering idempotence, scaling up, scaling down, and fractional framerates:

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    private readonly List<string> _originalFrames = new List<string>();

    public Test()
    {
        // 30 FPS for 10 seconds
        for (int f = 0; f < 300; f++)
        {
            _originalFrames.Add(string.Format("{0:0000000}.png", f));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_set_default_values()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 30, _originalFrames, 10);

        Assert.AreEqual(30, scaler.InputRate);
        Assert.AreEqual(30, scaler.OutputRate);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, scaler.StartIndex);
        Assert.AreEqual(_originalFrames.ElementAt(10), scaler.First());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_same_is_idempotent()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 30, _originalFrames);

        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.InputDuration, scaler.OutputDuration);
        Assert.AreEqual(_originalFrames.Count, scaler.Count());
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames.SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_same_offset_by_half_is_idempotent()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(
            30, 30, _originalFrames, _originalFrames.Count / 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(150, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames
            .Skip(150)
            .SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_60()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 60, _originalFrames);

        Assert.AreEqual(600, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        var result = scaler.ToList();
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames
            .Concat(_originalFrames)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_60_offset_by_half()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(
            30, 60, _originalFrames, _originalFrames.Count / 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(300, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames
            .Skip(150)
            .Concat(_originalFrames.Skip(150))
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_100()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 100, _originalFrames);

        Assert.AreEqual(1000, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        // 000 - 111 - 2222 ...
        Assert.IsTrue(scaler.PatternIs(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_100_offset_by_half()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(
            30, 100, _originalFrames, _originalFrames.Count / 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(500, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        // 000 - 111 - 2222 ...
        Assert.IsTrue(scaler.PatternIs(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_24p_to_ntsc()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(23.967, 29.97, _originalFrames);

        Assert.AreEqual(375, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(
            scaler.OutputDuration.TotalMilliseconds, 
            scaler.InputDuration.TotalMilliseconds, delta: 4);
        // 0 - 1 - 2 - 33 ...
        Assert.IsTrue(scaler.PatternIs(0, 1, 2, 3, 3));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_15()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 15, _originalFrames);

        Assert.AreEqual(150, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames
            .Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 1)
            .SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Scale_from_30_to_15_offset_by_half()
    {
        var scaler = new FramerateScaler<string>(30, 15, _originalFrames, 150);

        Assert.AreEqual(75, scaler.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(scaler.OutputDuration, scaler.InputDuration);
        Assert.IsTrue(_originalFrames
            .Skip(150)
            .Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 1)
            .SequenceEqual(scaler));
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static bool PatternIs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params int[] pattern)
    {
        foreach (var chunk in source.Chunkify(pattern.Length))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < chunk.Length; i++)
                if (!chunk.ElementAt(i).Equals(
                    chunk.Distinct().ElementAt(pattern[i])))
                    return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/3210961/3191599
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Chunkify<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (size < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
        using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                var chunk = new T[size];
                chunk[0] = iter.Current;
                for (int i = 1; i < size && iter.MoveNext(); i++)
                {
                    chunk[i] = iter.Current;
                }
                yield return chunk;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an elaborate answer. Thanks. I like the use of enumerators here.

Comment: The solution works well for individual test cases. I'm struggling with making it work for generating multiple sequences one after the other. the problem comes in when considering time as an input. So the user could say scale from 30FPS to 60FPS for 4 seconds, then scale to 15FPS for 2 seconds. How could I track which frames have been processed and set a time limit in the enumerator?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to create another instance of `FramerateScaler` for the new framerate, since it already allows you to specify a starting index. Then you'd have to add a new property that gives you the current input frame (or -1 for number of processed input frames). You'd also either have to calculate externally how many frames to pull from the iterator to get a specific length of time, or add it as another option to the enumerator's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`targetFrames.Add(originalFrames [originalStartFrameIndex + (int)(i * targetFrameRate / originalFrameRate) ]`

should do the trick. Add some error validation (check for divide by zero and exceeding the bounds of the array) :)